# Percorrendo estrutura complexa JSON com java Script

Tags: javascript, html5, json

Olá,

Estou começando agora no mundo do javascript, precisaria de ajuda para percorrer a seguinte estrutura de json:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso por exemplo incrementar um contador quando o campo "win" estiver como 'true', preciso guardar em variáveis o valor contido em determinados campos como o campo "gameType".

Meu Json(incorreto) está assim:

```
  for(i in json.games) 
    {    
        for (j in json.games[i].stats)
        {
            if (json.games[i].stats[j].win === true)
            {    
                console.log(json.games[i].stats[j]);
            }
        }    
    }
```

Grato desde já.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não é necessário tantas iterações. Na verdade só é necessário iterar o `json.games`.

Como a variável `json.games` é uma array, a melhor forma de iterá-la é com o método `forEach()` (atualmente, existem soluções mais rápidas pra se iterar uma array, mas ao passo que o `forEach()` é um método nativo ele é mais seguro e mais confortável além do próprio navegador se encarregar de iterar, dando mais liberdade no uso da máquina) que é nativo de toda array, a especificação do `forEach()` é relativamente nova, mas já tem [95%  de implementação nos navegadores do mundo e 97% de implementação no Brasil](http://caniuse.com/#search=foreach), portanto pode usar sossegado.

A [especificação do `forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) resumida:

```
var foo = [3, 4, "bar"];

foo.forEach(function(elemento, indice, arrayCompleta){
  console.log(elemento, indice, arrayCompleta);
});

// Console:
// 3, 0, [3, 4, "bar"]
// 4, 1, [3, 4, "bar"]
// "bar", 2, [3, 4, "bar"]
```

Outro problema no seu código, é que você iterou as propriedades também, como as propriedades sempre tem um nome fixo (por exemplo o `json.games[0].stats.win`) não é necessário iterar pra encontrá-las, apenas refenciá-las.

Aplicando no seu exemplo bastaria iterar a array `json.games` verificar se `elemento.stats.win == true` e guardar os valores que quiser. Se fizermos tudo ficaria assim:

```
var tipoJogo = [];

json.games.forEach(function(jogo){
  // Verificando se o jogo.win é verdadeiro
  // Quando se quer apenas saber se o valor é verdadeiro,
  // não é necessário compará-lo à true, apenas referenciá-lo
  // (jogo.stats.win) ao invés de (jogo.stats.win == true)
  if (jogo.stats.win) {
    console.log('Jogo ganho', jogo.stats.win);
  }

  // Guardando o gameType em outra variável
  // O método push() serve pra adicionar valores no final de uma array
  tipoJogo.push(jogo.gameType);
});
```

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado pela resposta e pela explicação dela, incrível como eu havia complicado tanto meu código.